# Tracking incoming App Referrals/Installs from facebook to my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I'm in desperate need of help.
I'm trying to analyze where my incoming traffic is coming from.

I have a facebook app with 100.000+ users and a lot of new organic sign ups each day. I see a lot of fluctuations in the sign ups (+/-50%) and I'm desperate to figure out where the inflow is coming from.

I've gone through facebook insights and found that 99% of the external referrers are coming from my own app and <0,5% is coming from various google engines.

I can see that a big boost initially came in when the app was trending/new and I've had a few peaks since with no apparent reason for it. Hence I have a hypothesis that it has something to do with the lists - but I really need help in how to confirm this.

Has anyone had the same frustrations as I - and more importantly what did they do about it?
-Do I need to setup some form of landing page where I capture the source address?
-Is there a online service like google analytics which can help me out?

Any help or direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not send referrer traffic to google play store. Play store allows us to track the install based on the referrer in the query parameter.

You can include the google analytics SDK to track the flow. I would recommend to make use of firebase analytics for app.

To get Facebook installs use FB analytics or make use of any Facebook marketing partner SDKs like appflyer